# how to scrape data using dt tags

Tags: php

I am scraping data from a url, mostly I have experienced `ul li` and so on.

This time I have found `dl` tags, and when I use scrape_between function it doesn't show me anything my code is :

```
<div id='gallery-1' class='gallery galleryid-273 gallery-columns-2 gallery-size-full'><dl class='gallery-item'>
        <dt class='gallery-icon portrait'>
            <a href='https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/gf-1.jpg?fit=650%2C976' data-rel="lightbox-gallery-1"><img  width="650" height="976"  src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7" data-src="https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/gf-1.jpg?fit=650%2C976"  class="attachment-full size-full" alt="" aria-describedby="gallery-1-16311" data-srcset="https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/gf-1.jpg?w=650 650w, https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/gf-1.jpg?resize=200%2C300 200w" data-sizes="(max-width: 650px) 100vw, 650px" /></a>
        </dt>
            <dd class='wp-caption-text gallery-caption' id='gallery-1-16311'>
            Ground Floor Plan
            </dd></dl><dl class='gallery-item'>
        <dt class='gallery-icon portrait'>
            <a href='https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/ff.jpg?fit=649%2C1024' data-rel="lightbox-gallery-1"><img  width="649" height="1024"  src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7" data-src="https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/ff.jpg?fit=649%2C1024"  class="attachment-full size-full" alt="" aria-describedby="gallery-1-16312" data-srcset="https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/ff.jpg?w=649 649w, https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/ff.jpg?resize=190%2C300 190w" data-sizes="(max-width: 649px) 100vw, 649px" /></a>
        </dt>
            <dd class='wp-caption-text gallery-caption' id='gallery-1-16312'>
            First Floor pLan
            </dd></dl><br style="clear: both" />
    </div>
```

Can anybody help me out ?

scrap_between function is

```
function scrape_between($data, $start, $end){
    $data = stristr($data, $start); 
    $data = substr($data, strlen($start));  
    $stop = stripos($data, $end);   
    $data = substr($data, 0, $stop);    
    return $data;   
}
```

I need to scrape images that are place in dt tags

I am trying this code

```
$project_images = scrape_between($data, '<dl class="gallery-item', '<br style="clear: both">');
```

Please suggest

Answer (score -1):

You could use a loop in your function and make it return an array:

```
//returns array with found elements
function scrape_between($data, $start, $end) {

    $html_array = explode($start, $data);

    $clean_html_arr = [];

    foreach ($html_array as $position => $html_array_element) {
      if ($position > 0) {
        $html_exploded = explode($end, $html_array_element);
        $clean_html_arr[] = $start . $html_exploded[0] . $end;
      }
    }

    return $clean_html_arr;
}
```

And use it like this:

```
//Test function
foreach(scrape_between($str, "<dl class='gallery-item'>", "</dl>") as $key => $htmlBlock) {
    echo htmlspecialchars($htmlBlock) . '<br><br>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer Nicky but I don't want to change my scrape_between function because I am using this on hundreds of other places

Answer (score -1):

Finally I got the solution myself I didn't find any answer of my question here so I decided to answer this to help others

I solved the problem to get dl images using this code

```
$data = 'your html content';

        if (preg_match("/<div id='gallery-1' class='gallery galleryid-273 gallery-columns-2 gallery-size-full'><dl class='gallery-item'>/",$data)){
            $data0 = explode("<dl class='gallery-item'>",$data);
            $proj_img = array();
            foreach($data0 as $key=> $imgArray)
            {
                $proj_img[$key] = scrape_between($imgArray, 'data-srcset="', '?w');
            }
            $proj_img = array_filter($proj_img);
            echo "<pre>"; print_r($proj_img);
        }
```